# Parametrized equation of hyperplane orthogonal to main diagonal

Tags: geometry, rotations

For the hyperplane passing through the origin and orthogonal to the ones vector,$(\underset{n\ \mbox{times}}{\underbrace{1,\dots,1})}$ in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, what are the $n-1$ remaining orthonormal basis vectors that span the plane in terms of the Cartesian coordinates, $(x_1,\dots,x_{n-1})$ of $\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$?

I started by thinking about the $(n-1)$-product of rotation matrices of 2D subspaces applied to the hyperplane, $(x_1,\dots,x_{n-1},0)$. Then I realized that the angles are not trivial and I thought there may be a better/more standard way?

If $\vec{a} \cdot \vec{y}=0$, $\vec{a},\vec{y}\in\mathbb{R}^n$, is the equation of the hyperplane (with the $a_i$s not-yet-determined), and the constraint of being orthogonal to the ones vector is $\sum_{i=1}^n{y_i}=0$. I would like to know the set of $n-1$ orthonormal vectors, $e_i=f_i(x_1,\dots,x_{n-1})$, $i=1,\dots,n-1$ that along with $e_n=(\underset{n\ \mbox{times}}{\underbrace{1,\dots,1})}$ span the space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $H$ denote the hyperplane in question. If you really want a linear parametrization of $H$ (instead of an implicit description, which can be found immediately from Aretino's answer), you need a basis $(v_{j})_{j=1}^{n-1}$ of $H$, such as
\begin{align*}
v_{1} &= (-1, 0, \dots, 0, 1) = -e_{1} + e_{n}, \\
v_{2} &= (0, -1, \dots, 0, 1) = -e_{2} + e_{n},\quad \dots \\
v_{n-1} &= (0, 0, \dots, -1, 1) = -e_{n-1} + e_{n}.
\end{align*}
If instead you want a parametrization in which the coordinates are "Cartesian", your basis needs to be orthonormal, e.g., obtained from $(v_{j})$ by [Gram-Schmidt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process).

In either case, you'd send $(x_{1}, \dots, x_{n-1}, 0)$ to
$$
\sum_{j=1}^{n-1} x_{j} v_{j}
  = x_{1}v_{1} + \dots + x_{n-1} v_{n-1}.
$$

Comment: This is the kind of answer I had in mind. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First write the coordinates as an equation. Then parametrize $n-1$ coördinates trivially. That is the easiest method.